# Copy data from one workbook to another after comparing date of entry

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from one workbook to another by comparing current system date.

`Billings ECCS` is the file I want to copy my data from to other workbook called `New`, and the worksheet is called `Billing Details`.

I want to copy only those data which belong to the current date of system. The `Billing ECCS` workbook contains worksheet called `Billing List` in which the first column is `Date of Entry`.

I want to compare that date with the systems current date and then copy the corresponding data to the other worksheet by finding the next empty row.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SendToBilling()
Option Explicit
Sub Macro2()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim eRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim wbMaster As Workbook
Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("file:///C:\Users\mrisingh\Desktop\Billing.xlsx")
With wbMaster.Worksheets("Billing Sheet")
LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Cells(i, 1) = Date Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Select
Selection.Copy  
eRow = Worksheets("Billing Details").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(eRow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next i
End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please understand that Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please read [ask] and [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) to edit and improve your question. Show what you already have tried and ask a proper question to it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I've updated my problem. Kindly look into it. Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't look too bad. What errors do you get? What goes wrong? • Some things I see: `wbMaster.Range` doesn't work because a workbook doesn't have a range. Instead use `.Range` the leading dot makes the range use the sheet from the `With` statement. All other `Range` and `Cells` should start with a dot too to use the `With` statement. Instead of `ActiveSheet` specify a sheet by its name like `Worksheets("New")`. Also have a look at: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: And don't use `Integer` for row counting. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. It is recommended [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA as there is no benefit in using Integer at all.

Comment: Dim LastRow As Long
Dim eRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim wbMaster As Workbook
Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("file:///C:\Users\mrisingh\Desktop\Billing.xlsx")
With wbMaster.Worksheets("Billing Sheet")
LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Cells(i, 1) = Date Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Select
Selection.Copy
eRow = Worksheets("Billing Details").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(eRow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next i
End With

Comment: ① Code in comments is not readable please always add code in your original question. ② If you don't tell which errors you get or what exactly is going wrong we cannot help.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I've made the suggested changes. There's no error coming but it is also not working. It just opens the other workbook and the respective worksheet I want to copy my data from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be explicit about which sheet is which

```
Sub SendToBilling()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim eRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mrisingh\Desktop\Billing ECCS.xlsx")

   Dim SourceSheet as worksheet
   Dim DestinationSheet as worksheet  

   Set Sourcesheet = wbmaster.worksheets("Billing List")
   set destinationsheet = Workbooks("New").worksheets("Billing Details")

'I think I've got these the right way round? Is your workbook really called NEW?


        LastRow = destinationsheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If sourcesheet.Cells(i, 1) = Date Then
                 eRow = destinationSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                sourcesheet.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).copy destinationsheet(erow,1)


              End If
        Next i
    End With  
End Sub
```

Comment: What are your sheets called - which is the source and which the destination? You wrote " to other workbook called New, and the worksheet is called Billing Details."

Comment: I want to copy from Workbook called "Billing ECCS" and worksheet called "Billing Sheet" to Workbook called "New" and worksheet called "Billing Details"

Comment: Format: Workbook>Worksheet, Source: Billing ECCS>Billing Sheet, Destination: New>Billing Details

Comment: Change to 
Set Sourcesheet = wbmaster.worksheets("Billing sheet")

Though your original question wrote " The Billing ECCS workbook contains worksheet called Billing List "

Comment: I'm sorry for that but the required changes have been made. Still it's just opening the source sheet, i.e., Billing Sheet and not working further.

Comment: use F8 to step through the code and see where it stops - are you sure there's some data to be copied?